# Implementing socket write timeout

Tags: c, sockets

Hi I'm trying to know if data wasn't send through the socket after a period of time, I tried to implement it like so:

```
int write_t(int sock, void *buf, unsigned int len){
  fd_set set;
  struct timeval timeout;
  int rv;

  FD_ZERO(&set);
  FD_SET(sock, &set);

  timeout.tv_sec = RW_TIMEOUT;
  timeout.tv_usec = 0;

  rv = select(sock + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
  if(rv == -1)
    return -1;
  else if(rv == 0)
    return -2;
  else
    return write( sock, (unsigned int *)buf, len );
}
```

however when I'm using this code the program blocks for `timeout.tv_sec` seconds and doesn't send anything.
What is the problem here?
How can I implement write timeout correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want write on this socket why don't your use `fd_set *writefds` argument of `select()` ? What you want "if data wasn't send through the socket" and your [mcve] differs a lot.

Comment: One simple way to implement timeouts on a POSIX system like Linux or macOS is to use [`alarm`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/alarm.2.html). With a suitable setup signal handler this will cause `write` to return with the error `EINTR`.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer No. There is no such thing as 'wait (without timeout) for the write to complete'. It is you who has it backwards.

Comment: Or use non-blocking sockets, `write` the data and then forget about it?

Comment: Lastly, what is the *actual* problem you want to solve with a timeout? You only ask us about your wanted solution, but you don't tell us what the problem it is supposed to solve. Please edit your question to include that information, and we might be able to help you with *that* problem instead. [Related reading about the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Great, so if he gets EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK we just forget about that piece of data altogether? NB `alarm()` is not reentrant. The 'actual problem' he wants to solve is implementing a write timeout. It's not an extraordinary requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the FD into the `readfds`, so you're blocking in select until the socket becomes readable, which doesn't happen, so you get the timeout. You should set it into the `writefds`.

Note that what you're doing doesn't guarantee that the data was actually sent. It guarantees that *some* data was *transferred* into the socket send buffer, from whence it will get sent as and when TCP determines, asynchronously to the write.

Comment: In other words, change the line `rv = select(sock + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);` to  `rv = select(sock + 1, NULL, &set, NULL, &timeout);`.

Comment: @Marian You can't win. If you just post code they ask for an explanation. If you post an explanation they just say 'u send me codes'. I only post explanations except under duress.